# JavaScript prototypes equivalance for functions

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am reading JavaScript: Good parts by Douglas Crockford. I came across this following useful trick.

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    if (!this.prototype[name]) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
    }
};
```

Based on the above code snippet, what I understood is, as all functions are objects of `Function` and as the above function adds the `'method'` method to prototype of `Function`, there will be a `method` method available on all functions.

```
var pfun = function(name){
    this.name = name;
};
```

Consider the following log statements

```
console.log(Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(pfun));//true - Thats fine
console.log(pfun.prototype == Function.prototype);//false - why?
```

I couldn't understand why the above logs contradict each other.

Here `pfun` is a functions which has the `method` method available from its prototype. So I can call the following.

```
pfun.method("greet",function(){
      console.log(this.name);
});
```

Now as `method` method runs, it adds the `greet` method to `pfun`'s prototype. If the above logs doesn't contradict each other, then `greet` method should be available to all functions.

My question is, why the above logs are contradicting each other?

Comment: You can check that Function is the prototype of the pfun like this: `pfun.__proto__ == Function.prototype`

Comment: You are confusing the [\[\[Prototype\]\] internal property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) with the [`prototype` property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.2).

Comment: What Oriol said, except **internal** `[[Prototype]]` (which is Function.prototype) vs public *prototype*, which is an empty Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*isPrototypeOf*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.6) checks to see if an object is referenced by the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of another object.

All ECMAScript native functions inherit from *Function.prototype* therefore:

```
Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(pfun))
```

returns true.

Every native function created by the Function constructor has a default public *prototype* property that is a plain object (see [ECMAScript §13.2 #16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)). So when you do:

```
pfun.prototype == Function.prototype
```

you are comparing this plain object to *Function.prototype*<sup>1</sup>, which are different objects.

This confusion is brought about in discussion because the public and private prototype properties are often only distinguished by the context in which the term is used. All native Functions have both, and only for the Function constructor are they the same object by default, i.e.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Function.prototype
```

returns true. This relationship can be established for other Objects, but it doesn't happen by default (and I can't think of an example or sensible reason to do it).

<sup>1</sup> The *Function.prototype* object is a bit of an oddity. It has an internal `[[Class]]` value of "function" and is callable, so in that regard it's a function. However, its internal `[[Prototype]]` is *Object.prototype*, so it can probably be called an instance of Object. When called, it ignores all arguments and returns *undefined*.

Comment: Nitpicking: `Function.prototype` is a native function which doesn't inherit from itself. If weren't for backwards compatibility, ES6 would have fixed that oddity by making it an ordinary object.

Answer (score 0):

They don't contradict each other. Your `pfun` has a prototypal inheritance from `Function`, but it's not a reference to Function's prototype. It has its own prototype (that is derived from Function's one).

So, when you ask if `Function.prototype.isPrototypeOf(pfun)`, you get `true`, because `pfun`'s prototype is derived from Function's one. But when you ask if `pfun.prototype` is equal to `Function.prototype`, you get `false`, because it's false, `pfun` has its own prototype.

The method `greet` is added only to the `pfun`'s prototype, and not to the `Function`'s one.

But if you do:

```
Function.prototype.method('greet', function() {
  console.log(this.name);
});
```

Then, all the `function`'s prototypes (that will be derived from `Function.prototype`) will have the `greet` method in its prototype, because of the prototypal inheritance.